# Selenium remotewebdriver starts browser binary but doesn't get a webdriver - how can I clean up the browser process

Tags: selenium, firefox, browser, remotewebdriver, resource-cleanup

We are running in an infrastructure that sometimes gets very bogged down. What we are seeing happening is that when we make the remotewebdriver call, the firefox.exe is started but because the machine is so slow and we have a 15 second timeout, creating the webdriver does not succeed. So we fail but now we have a rouge firefox process out there using up memory - after tons of builds are kicked off against our remote selenium machines, we see hundreds of leftover firefox processes sitting out there.  I can't do a close or quit on the driver - I don't have a driver since the call to remotewebdriver failed.... how can I know what firefox process we just created to kill it?  Is this something that should be cleaned up by selenium? We are using java.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned `firefox.exe is started but because the machine is so slow and we have a 15 second timeout, creating the webdriver does not succeed` and `see hundreds of leftover firefox processes sitting out there`, I have a **4** point solution which may work for you.

1. As our aim is to test the Application so I think we must not tinker with the loading of the page anyway. Setting a `15 second timeout` will only fail our attempts to bring up the Application live to start the Testing process. Hence a better alternative would be to let the `WebDriver` instance bring up the Application live normally so `Selenium` gets a clean [**`Document.readyState == complete`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) from the [**`DOM tree`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)
2. As you spoke of machine is slow, the very next action would be to ensure the `Test Bed` is configured with required `Hardware (CPU, RAM, ROM, Cache) and Software (Selenium, WebDriver, WebBrowser versions) resources`. Ensure that the `Test Machines` running the `Automation Script` and the `Testcases` are isolated from other User Interactions.
3. Further if you want to cut off the page loading time and want to start interecting with the `WebElements` as soon as they are loaded in that case you may consider to tweak the **`pageLoadStrategy`**. The default setting for **`pageLoadStrategy`** is **`normal`** which we can change it to **`eager`**. Setting **`pageLoadStrategy`** to **`eager`** implies that as soon as the `WebElements` are loaded in the `HTML DOM` and is **`interactive`**, your script resumes execution.
4. Now, your main concern of `hundreds of leftover firefox processes sitting out there` can be handled by keeping the blocker part of code in a `try` block. If code block within `try` succeeds our script proceeds. Incase `try` fails, we will call `quit()` in the `catch()` block so the Firefox Browser instance and the `WebDriver` instance exits gracefully. A blue print of the code block is as follows:

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class Q45703729_firefox_process {

       public static void main(String[] args) {


           System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
           try {
               driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
               System.out.println("Application opened");
           } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println("Unable to open Application. Quiting ...");
               driver.quit();
           }
           System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
           //Do other tasks
           driver.quit();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: For 1 Point :- the phrase `firefox.exe is started but because the machine....` you are emphasizing and intend to reply  is enclosed in code format So i guess it would be better if you make it  Italicize or bold. Point 2: yes there is no issue at all with the curly braces i changes them for more readability. Any way i have rollback the changes.

Comment: Points 2 and 3 are irrelevant to my question.  Point 1 isn't a valid answer for me either - in this situation, the page will very likely never load. The firefox.exe process is started but the geckodriver.exe is not.  I need a way to clean it up. Therefore - point 4 is also invalid for me as I do not ever get a driver.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such kind of issues you should make sure that `driver.quit()` is called when browser is not required anymore.

Assuming Java stack, most likely you're using TestNG or JUnit framework. The best place for resources' releasing would be either one of `@After...` methods (depending on chosen session management strategy), or special listeners. For example:

```
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null)
        driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a driver - you missed that part - the driver didn't get created - only the firefox process....

Comment: @A.Reitmeyer no, I haven't missed that. As well as you haven't provided any stacktrace and grid log / configuration. Be more specific in details please. Especially when you talk about timeouts.

Comment: Selenium / browser / driver versions specification would be helpful as well.